# Mysql do not select duplicated values, conditional

Tags: mysql, select, duplicates

I am looking for a way to run a simple `SELECT` statement. I have a table which has three columns: `ID`, `TITLE` and `ACTIVE`, where `ACTIVE` column represents a `boolean` value.

```
1. foo false
2. foo false
3. foo true
4. bar false
5. bar false
6. aaa false
7. ccc false
8. ccc true
```

I want it to return the following:

```
4. bar false
5. aaa false
```

Comment: You need to add some more details to the question. What is the business rule that is driving the selection of this result?

Comment: I assume the second result line should be `6. aaa false`?

Comment: Did any of the answers help?

Answer (score 0):

This will show TITLES that have only a single ACTIVE value (this is what you are looking for, correct?), and the MIN ID for this TITLE.

```
SELECT MIN(ID) ID, TITLE, ACTIVE

FROM   YOURTABLE

GROUP BY TITLE

HAVING MIN(ACTIVE) = MAX(ACTIVE)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding it right, you are retrieving those rows that are having only `false` value, then this should help you:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
   SELECT  `ID` ,  `TITLE` ,  `ACTIVE` 
   FROM  `table_name` 
   GROUP BY  `TITLE`
) AS  `t` 
WHERE t.`ACTIVE` = 0
```

Also I think for boolean values you need to have either `0` or `1`.